# How do you split linestrings from a shapefile at 10km vertices?

Tags: r, gis, rgdal, r-sf

I have a shapefile of river segments that I've imported into R. The segments range in length from 5-115km. I want to split the segments that are over 10km into 10km chunks. So I use `st_segmentize`. But this doesn't actually split a long line into multiple new shorter lines, which is what I want... Is there a way to do this? I think `st_segmentize` just adds vertices every 10km. So I just need to split the lines at the vertices.

Code so far:

```
library("sf")
rivers = st_read("./YukonMain4_copy.shp", layer = 'YukonMain4_copy')
seg = st_segmentize(rivers, units::set_units(10,km))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share a minimal example dataset that replicates your problem? See this post for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Phil, you got it.  I'll work on creating an example data set, but I'm very new to 'sf' so it might take a while (so standby for that)! The problem is that I don't know how to split large line segments into smaller line segments, and I'm wondering if folks know of a function to do this.

Comment: I don't off the top of my head, but if you have an small shapefiles of lines to play with I can test a few things. Of course, someone might be able to just say, "it's function `x`", but it's always best to try and provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Ok, so I made a sample shapefile that you could download,  but I don't see a place to upload it..... I am really struggling to figure out a way to write code that makes a sample line for you to test with. I'll keep on it though.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Try posting gis questions on http://gis.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: I'll give that a go instead, thanks.